# cake PHP data not save to database table

Tags: php, cakephp

Controller created for  **UserController.php**

```
public function myappointment() {

        $this->loadmodel('event');
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
           $this->Event->create();

            if ($this->Event->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your appointment has been saved.'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your appointment.'));
            }
        }
    }
```

model name for **event**
event.php

```
class Event extends UserMgmtAppModel {


}
```

**appointment form code in view**

```
<?php 
 $this->Form->create('Event');

echo $this->Form->input("title" ,array('label' => false ));

 echo $this->Form->input("from", array('label' =>false, 'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'fl tal vat w300p', 'error' => false , 'id' => 'select_date'));
 echo $this->Html->div('datepicker_img w100p fl pl460p pa', $this->Html->image('calendar.png'),array('id' => 'datepicker_img')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->div('datepicker fl pl460p pa', ' ' ,array('id' => 'datepicker'));
echo 'End time';
 echo $this->Form->input("to", array('label' =>false, 'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'fl tal vat w300p', 'error' => false , 'id' => 'select_date1'));
 echo $this->Html->div('datepicker_img1 w100p fl pl460p pa', $this->Html->image('calendar.png'),array('id' => 'datepicker_img1')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->div('datepicker1 fl pl460p pa', ' ' ,array('id' => 'datepicker1'));

echo $this->Form->end('Create appointment');
```

Comment: can u please tell me how to insert a values to database . we need for a steps to create controller , model, ctp file

Comment: `class Event extends UserMgmtAppModel {` are you sure about this?

Comment: yes class create like that

Comment: hello mr.mjhm can we tell me cakephp tutorial sites

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar  UserMgmtAppModel tis a plugin

Comment: Your have to load your model inside plugin then. Check my answer

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar still i got error Error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object  File: E:\wamp\www\testwork\cakephp-2.4.5\app\Plugin\Usermgmt\Controller\UsersControlle‌​r.php  Line: 547

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your model.

```
App::uses('UserMgmtAppModel', 'Event.Model');

class Event extends UserMgmtAppModel {

}
```

Your controller action

```
  public function myappointment() {

    $this->loadmodel('Event');
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
       $this->Event->create();

        if ($this->Event->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your appointment has been saved.'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your appointment.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **still i got error** Error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object 
File: E:\wamp\www\testwork\cakephp-2.4.5\app\Plugin\Usermgmt\Controller\UsersController.php 
Line: 547

Comment: `$this->loadmodel('event');` should be `$this->loadmodel('Event');`. I have edited my answer, Now check